Incorrect results when training a SRGAN using Wavelet transform on the images
I'm training an SRGAN. My process is as follows:
High res images are read. Which are 256 X 256 X 3
Low res images are created from the high res ones. Which are 32 X 32 X 3
Both high res and low res images are split into RGB channels.
For each channel wavelet transform is applied to get 4 coefficients. So 3 channels X 4 = 12 channels. For each high res image the dimension becomes 256 X 256 X 12 and similarly for each low res image the dims are 32 X 32 X 12.
These are my generator and discriminator:
def build_generator(num_res_blocks=32):
    input_lr = Input(shape=(32, 32, 12), name='input_lr')  # Adjusted for 12 channels

    # Initial feature extraction
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=9, padding='same', name='initial_conv')(input_lr)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu', name='initial_activation')(x)

    # Save the input without activation for the residual connection
    x_res = x

    # Residual blocks
    for i in range(num_res_blocks):
        x = residual_block(x, prefix=f'res_block_{i}')

    # Post-residual block
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', name='post_conv')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = add([x_res, x], name='post_add')
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    # Upsampling
    x = UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4), name='upsampling')(x)  # Adjusted for upsampling to 128x128

    # Output layer to reconstruct the high-resolution output
    output_hr = Conv2D(12, kernel_size=9, padding='same', activation='tanh', name='output_hr')(x)  # Adjusted for 12 channels

    model = Model(inputs=input_lr, outputs=output_hr)
    return model

def build_discriminator():
    input_hr = Input(shape=(128, 128, 12), name='input_hr')  # Adjusted for 12 channels

    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', name='conv1')(input_hr)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    # More convolutional layers
    x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', name='conv3')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', name='conv4')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, name='dense')(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=input_hr, outputs=output)
    return model


And this is my training loop:
def train_discriminator_step(real_images, generated_images, discriminator):
    # Train the discriminator on real and fake images, separately
    real_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(real_images, np.ones((real_images.shape[0], 1)))
    fake_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(generated_images, np.zeros((generated_images.shape[0], 1)))
    d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(real_loss, fake_loss)
    return d_loss

def train_generator_step(gan_input, gan_labels, gan_model):
    # Train the generator
    g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(gan_input, gan_labels)
    return g_loss



# Placeholder for manually tracking loss
best_g_loss = np.inf
best_d_loss = np.inf

disc_lr = 0.0002
gan_lr = 0.0001

prev_d_loss = float('inf')
prev_g_loss = float('inf')

patience = 5
wait = 0
factor = 0.5  # Factor by which to reduce the lr
min_lr = 1e-6

# Assume X_train_lr and X_train_hr are your low-res and high-res training datasets, respectively.
# They should be shaped as (num_samples, height, width, 12), with pixel values normalized between -1 and 1.

# Compile the discriminator
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(disc_lr, 0.5), metrics=['accuracy'])


# Combine generator and discriminator for the GAN model
discriminator.trainable = False  # Make the discriminator not trainable when training the generator
gan_input = Input(shape=(32, 32, 12))
gan_output = discriminator(generator(gan_input))
gan_model = Model(gan_input, gan_output)

# Compile the GAN model
gan_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(gan_lr, 0.5))


# epochs = 10000  # Adjust the number of epochs based on your dataset size and desired quality
epochs = 10000

for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}")
    epoch_g_loss = []
    epoch_d_loss = []
    batch_index = 0 
    
    for batch_index, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
        imgs_lr, imgs_hr = batch  # Assuming you have LR and HR image pairs in the dataset
        # batch_size = len(imgs_hr)  # Update batch size based on the current batch

        # Generate high-resolution images from low-resolution images
        generated_images = generator.predict(imgs_lr)

        if batch_index % 2 == 0:
            # Train the discriminator on real and fake images, separately
            d_loss = train_discriminator_step(imgs_hr, generated_images, discriminator)
        
        # Train the generator
        gan_input = imgs_lr  # Input to the generator
        # gan_labels = np.ones((batch_size, 1))  # We want the discriminator to classify generated images as real
        gan_labels = noisy_labels(np.ones((batch_size, 1)), 0.05)  # We want the discriminator to classify generated images as real
        g_loss = train_generator_step(gan_input, gan_labels, gan_model)


        # Dynamically update learning rates for both the discriminator and the generator
        if d_loss[0] < prev_d_loss:
            prev_d_loss = d_loss[0]
            wait = 0
        else:
            wait += 1
            if wait >= patience:
                d_old_lr = discriminator.optimizer.lr.numpy()
                d_new_lr = max(min_lr, factor * d_old_lr)
                discriminator.optimizer.lr.assign(d_new_lr)
                if d_old_lr != d_new_lr:
                    print(f'D_lr updated to { d_new_lr } from { d_old_lr }')
                wait = 0

        if g_loss < prev_g_loss:
            prev_g_loss = g_loss
            wait = 0
        else:
            wait += 1
            if wait >= patience:
                g_old_lr = gan_model.optimizer.lr.numpy()
                g_new_lr = max(min_lr, factor * g_old_lr)
                gan_model.optimizer.lr.assign(g_new_lr)
                if g_old_lr != g_new_lr:
                    print(f'G_lr updated to { g_new_lr } from { g_old_lr }')
                wait = 0

        
        psnr_val_arr = []
        ssim_val_arr = []
        if batch_index % 2 == 0:
            val_sub_dt = val_dataset.take(5)
            for data_pair in val_sub_dt:
                vimg_lr, vimg_hr = data_pair
                vimg_lr = tf.expand_dims(vimg_lr, axis=0)
                val_pred = generator.predict(vimg_lr)
                psnr_val, ssim_val = calculate_metrics(vimg_hr, np.squeeze(val_pred))
                psnr_val_arr.append(psnr_val)
                ssim_val_arr.append(ssim_val)
                
            print(f'Average psnr_val: { sum(psnr_val_arr)/len(psnr_val_arr) }, Average ssim_val: { sum(ssim_val_arr)/len(ssim_val_arr) }')


        with tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs').as_default():
            tf.summary.scalar('D_loss', d_loss[0], step=epoch)
            tf.summary.scalar('G_loss', g_loss, step=epoch)
            if len(psnr_val_arr) > 0:
                tf.summary.scalar('psnr_val', sum(psnr_val_arr)/len(psnr_val_arr), step=epoch)
            if len(ssim_val_arr) > 0:
                tf.summary.scalar('ssim_val', sum(ssim_val_arr)/len(ssim_val_arr), step=epoch)


        # Save generator if it improved
        if g_loss < best_g_loss:
            best_g_loss = g_loss
            generator.save(generator_best_path)

        # Save discriminator if it improved
        if d_loss[0] < best_d_loss:
            best_d_loss = d_loss[0]
            discriminator.save(discriminator_best_path)

        print(f'D_loss: {d_loss[0]}, G_loss: {g_loss}, Epoch #: {epoch}, Batch #: {batch_index}')
        batch_index += 1  # Increment batch_index for each processed batch
        
        epoch_g_loss.append(g_loss)
        epoch_d_loss.append(d_loss[0])
    
    # Calculate mean loss for the epoch
    mean_g_loss = np.mean(epoch_g_loss)
    mean_d_loss = np.mean(epoch_d_loss)

So if I test the trained gan on this LR image:
Low Res Image
The GAN generates this output after about 100 epochs.
GAN Output
While the original HR image is the following:
High Res Image Original
Now my question is, what am I doing wrong and if possible how can I improve the results?
